# awk setting variables to make a range

Tags: variables, awk

I have the following two files:

File 1:

```
1 290 rs1345
2 450 rs5313
1 1120 rs4523
2 790 rs4325
```

File 2:

```
1 201 LDLR
2 714 APOA5
1 818 NOTCH5
1 514 TTN
```

I wish to isolate only the rows in file 2 in which the second field is within 100 units of the second field in file 1 (if field 1 matches):

Desired output: (note the third field is from the matching line in file1).

```
1 201 LDLR rs1345
2 714 APOA5 rs4325
```

I tried using the following code:

```
for i in {1..4} #there are 4 lines in file2
do
chr=$(awk 'NR=="'${i}'" { print $1 }' file2)
pos=$(awk 'NR=="'${i}'" { print $2 }' file2)
gene=$(awk 'NR=="'${i}'" { print $3 }' file2)

start=$(echo $pos | awk '{print $1-100}') #start and end variables for 100 unit range
end=$(echo $pos | awk '{print $1+100}')
awk '{if ($1=="'$chr'" && $2 > "'$start'" && $2 < "'$end'") print "'$chr'","'$pos'","'$gene'"$3}' file1
done
```

The code is not working, I believe something is wrong with my start and end variables, because when I echo $start, I get 414, which doesn't make sense to me and I get 614 when i echo $end.

I understand this question might be difficult to understand so please ask me if any clarification is necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: You can do this all in awk instead of this mess of awk and shell. Load the contents of the first file into an array and then use it while looping over the second file.

Comment: You want to print lines from file 2 if _any_ line in file 1 has a matching field 1 and a within-100 field 2?  What if more than one line in file 1 has a matching field 1 and a within-100 field 2?

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty is that $1 is not a unique key, so some care needs to be taken with the data structure to store the data in file 1.

With GNU awk, you can use arrays of arrays:

```
gawk '
    NR==FNR {f1[$1][$2] = $3; next} 
    $1 in f1 {
        for (val in f1[$1]) 
            if (val-100 <= $2 && $2 <= val+100) 
                print $0, f1[$1][val]
    }
' file1 file2
```

Otherwise, you have to use a one-dimensional array and stuff 2 pieces of information into the key:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {f1[$1,$2] = $3; next} 
    {
        for (key in f1) {
            split(key, a, SUBSEP) 
            if (a[1] == $1 && a[2]-100 <= $2 && $2 <= a[2]+100) 
                print $0, f1[key]
        }
    }
' file1 file2
```

That works with mawk and nawk (and gawk)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

file1 = """
1 290 rs1345
2 450 rs5313
1 1120 rs4523
2 790 rs4325
"""

file2 = """
1 201 LDLR
2 714 APOA5
1 818 NOTCH5
1 514 TTN
"""

sio = StringIO(file1)
df1 = pd.read_table(sio, sep=" ", header=None)
df1.columns = ["a", "b", "c"]

sio = StringIO(file2)
df2 = pd.read_table(sio, sep=" ", header=None)
df2.columns = ["a", "b", "c"]

df = pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on="a", right_on="a", how="outer")

#query is intuitive
r = df.query("b_y-100 < b_x <b_y + 100")
print r[["a", "b_x", "c_x", "c_y"]]
```

output:

```
   a  b_x    c_x     c_y
0  1  201   LDLR  rs1345
7  2  714  APOA5  rs4325
```

pandas is the right tool to do such tabular data manipulation.